# Extending class with generic parameter

Tags: java

I need to derive from the following class:

```
public abstract class MyTool<VIEW extends MyView>
  implements LookupListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener {}
```

The following does not work:

```
public abstract class MySubTool<VIEW> extends MyTool<VIEW> {}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler in MySubTool as no way of knowing that `VIEW` in `MySubTool` is a subclass of `MyView`, you have to specify it again:

```
public abstract class MySubTool<VIEW extends MyView> extends MyTool<VIEW> {}
```

Comment: Here is what the compiler reports: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor MyView()
location: class com.mysystem.viewer.MyView<VIEW>
    public MySubTool() {

Comment: This is unrelated to your previous problem, which was about generics. Your new problems is about constructors. Your base class has no default constructors, so you have to specify in ``MySubTool`` which constructor you want to call using ``super``.

Comment: oops sorry for the noise. Thanks for your great help !

Answer (score 1):

This should:

```
public abstract class MySubTool<VIEW extends MyView> extends MyTool<VIEW> {}
```